# Stackoverflow.com favorite tags do not highlight

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-watching, tag-highlighting

I added jQuery a little while ago to my favorite tags, and since then it has never highlighted the posts with jQuery as a tag. Is this a bug, or am I missing something.

[image: Screenshot of a search for jQuery]

Comment: What's the point of highlighting *every search result* for your favorite tag?

Comment: This is not ordinary search - if you search for a keyword which is not tag name, all posts containing one of your favorite tags will be highlighted.

Answer (score 10):

If you're in a favorite tag, searching for it specifically, we purposefully **do not** highlight.  Highlighting is intended to, ya know, *highlight* things among others, showing which ones are special.

If *all* questions are highlighted it really doesn't make any sense, so we don't do it, this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)